# Apply !important to font-family with more than one option

Tags: css

How can I apply !important to the following syle:

```
font-family: "Trebuchet MS" , Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
```

I've tried this, but doesn't work:

```
font-family: "Trebuchet MS" , Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif !important;
```

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: If I only had one option in font-family I could do:   font-family: "Trebuchet MS"!important; But I'd like to apply !important to all options.

Comment: above css looks perfectly valid to me

Comment: That's the right way to write it

Comment: Yeah, above code should work just fine.

Comment: works without trouble: http://jsfiddle.net/9eGtR/

Comment: I think it is generally a good idea to avoid `!important` and instead make your selectors more specific, i.e. replace `p.my-paragraph` with `#page-wrapper #content.my-class p.my-paragraph` to make sure the rules you specify are not overridden somewhere else.

Comment: Should work, unless you're testing this on IE6 or earlier (in which case, stop worrying - http://www.ie6countdown.com/ ;)

Comment: Sorry all for wasting your time, the style on my page isnt applied for some other reason then. I thought I was using !important incorrectly, which thanks to you guys I now know I wasn't, thanks again. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is fine. It would vary depending on which elements you are giving the property to. It's better if you use specific selectors such as classes:

http://jsfiddle.net/4d3K4/

Comment: Interestingly, this one doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/ArtixZ/h4y5wkod/.
Style from wrapper element with `!important` won't override font-family defined inner.

Answer (score 26):

Select the children within the parent container with a wildcard (*):

```css
div * {font-family: "Trebuchet MS" , Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif !important; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4d3K4/50/

Comment: The wildcard worked and seems to override the `font-family` style set by classes while`!important` alone doesn't work