# Why doesn't font-family accept !important?

Tags: html, css

The font-family with `!important` is disabled in this case. I can't understand it.

I just want to apply font "OpenSan" for any element except element with class BaseConsumer-sample-197

[image]

Comment: Need more information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524324/apply-important-to-font-family-with-more-than-one-option

Comment: i would suggest to avoid the !important in this case and give the text a class of the font you would like to implement.

Comment: Give specific CSS styles based on classes and you will not have to face this problem or use !important.

Comment: *I just want to apply font "OpenSan" for any element except element with class BaseConsumer-sample-197* --> and the element you are shown doesn't have the .BaseConsumer-sample-197 class. in the console you can read *inherited from*

Comment: You can't force inherit the `font-family` by adding `!important`. You either have to apply the `font-family` directly to the text containing element or refactor the body font-family something like this `body { /* font-family here */ }` instead of `body *:not(i) { /* font-family here */  }`.

Comment: Do you mean _except element with class BaseConsumer-sample-197 **and its children**_?

Comment: Thank all, I understand it, the key for this case is "font-family" can not be inherited. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -2):

Remove Font Family from the body then check.

Comment: Thank you
But I want to keep this css for other element.
Is there any solution for this case?

Comment: Yes you will have to go and look what is overriding your !important and change that statement not to override your  !important statement or move your !important to become the first statement. It gets confusing best is to give that font you would like to be in the specific font a class. That is the same reason why we add bootstrap to the very top of our page.